# Is it possible to use Open XML SDK V 2.5 with Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, openxml

Is it possible to use Open XML SDK V2.5 with Visual Studion 2005?

What is the lowest .Net framework it supports?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use Open XML SDK V2.5 with Visual Studio 2005?

I think it is. Opening it doesn't require some exact version of Visual Studio.

> What is the lowest .Net framework it supports?

From [`System Requirements`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425):

> Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2003 R2 (32-Bit x86), Windows
>   Server 2003 R2 x64 editions, Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2,
>   Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012,
>   Windows Vista Service Pack 1, Windows Vista Service Pack 2, Windows XP
>   Service Pack 3
>
> This download requires the following:
>
> - **The Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.0.**
> - Up to 300 MB of available disk space.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to have Open XML SDK v2.0 installed on your machine. I have both v2.0 and v2.5 installed. In VS2005 when I click 'Add Reference' for my project, I see both appear in the list, as in image below

[image: DocumentFormat.OpenXml available versions to reference]

However, even if I select 2.5.zzzz.z version it adds the 2.0.zzzz.z version to the project, which I verified by right clicking on the added reference and looking at its properties.

Version 2.5 got installed on my machine as a result of selections during installation of VS2019. On VS2005 however, I was seeing a yellow warning sign, before I installed Open XML SDK v2.0 and added reference to it. Then, my project also built successfully.

[image: DocumentFormat.OpenXml referenced v2.0 only]

When I tried the same in VS2019, adding reference to v2.0 successfully adds reference to it, and adding reference to v2.5 successfully adds reference to 2.5